# Spring Maven - Failed to load ApplicationContext NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, autowired

I encounter a exception in **test phase** when try to build my project.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=findUserByLogin)}
```

## Project consist with 4 modules:

```
AdviceExchange
    ├── domain
    ├── dao
    ├── service
    ├── web
```

## DAO classes (here occur throws exception)

```
package com.dozortsev.adviceexchange.dao;
import com.dozortsev.adviceexchange.domain.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import static java.lang.String.format;
import static org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation.MANDATORY;

@Transactional(propagation = MANDATORY)
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Long, User> implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private String findUserByLogin;   // Spring can't Autowired this String

    public UserDaoImpl() {
        this.entityClass = User.class;
    }

    @Override public User findByLogin(String login) {
        try {
            log.info(format("Finding %s by Login: %s", getEntityClass(), login));
            User user = (User) getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(findUserByLogin)
                        .addEntity(getEntityClass()).setString("login", login)
                        .uniqueResult();

            if (user != null) {
                log.info("Successful found");
                return user;
            }
            log.info(format("%s not exist", getEntityClass()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error: ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What wrong with my **ApplicationContext** ? Please help me with solve this issue.

Comment: Please shorten your question to just include relevant code. No need to dump everything which is not even relevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an import of the dao-application-context.xml in the test application context.  Since for testing purposes, you are using a separate data source, you should add 1 more application context file with the shared beans needed in both the real dao-application-context and the test-application context.  That is, create a new context file shared-application-context.xml with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"...>
    <!-- Queries -->
    <bean id="findUserByLogin" class="java.lang.String">
       <constructor-arg index="0"
                     value="
                     SELECT u.* FROM
                        user u, badge b, user_badge ub
                     WHERE
                        u.user_id = ub.ub_user_id
                        AND
                        b.bdg_id = ub.ub_badge_id
                        AND
                        u.user_email = :login"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Then import that into both the dao-application-context.xml and the test application context file using:

```
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/shared-application-context.xml"/>
```

Comment: Yes! This solve, thank you but now I have new exception: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`.

Comment: The test-application-context.xml loaded by the abstract TestContext class via @ContextConfiguration(locations = "/META-INF/spring/test-application-context.xml").  That file doesn't define any string beans.  You could also put that bean ("findUserByLogin") into the test context file, but then you risk them getting out of sync.

Comment: I fix the `No Session found for current thread`. Add `<import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/dao-application-context.xml"/>` in  [here](http://goo.gl/bsvxaA) but why we don't see my `SessionFactory` in this file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@Qualifier` then use

```
bean name="findUserByLogin"
```

instead of

```
bean id="findUserByLogin"
```

Comment: Actually I don't use `@Qualifier` but the error stay the same. I remove this annotation from code.

Comment: In my opinion this error related with `ApplicationContext`.